# How do I make a paragraph reappear and stop the previous animation when the mouse unhovers an element?

Tags: jquery

I want to make an animation start as soon as I trigger an event for eg in the following code the hover event is not immediate and hence the mouseout event takes ensures that the hover event has completed before starting its own..In other words,I want to terminate the hover event as soon as I mouseout on it...How can I fix this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <title>JQuery(2)</title>
<style type="text/css">
.Test1{width:100px;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="jquery.js">  </script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
$("h2").hover(function(){
    $(".Test1").animate({opacity:0},5000);
},
function(){
        //$(".Test1").stop();

         $(".Test1").animate({opacity:1},5000);
    })
});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<h2>Family Members</h2>

<p class="Test1">This is a textThis is a textThis is a textThis is a textThis is a textThis is a textThis is a textThis is a textThis is a textThis is a textThis is a textThis is a textThis is a textThis is a textThis is a textThis is a text</p>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LYPRV/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
$("h2").hover(function() {
    $(".Test1").stop().animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, 5000);
}, function() {
    $(".Test1").stop().animate({
        opacity: 1
    }, 5000);
});
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/LYPRV/4/
(*a bit faster, because 5 seconds to fade some text is to much ..*)

Comment: WHat does stop do here..As I have moved my mouse out of the element,the .Test1 has a somewhat fading effect..Why is that?

Comment: stops the previous animation queues and starts with the immediate one!!

Comment: @Vimal, it stops the current animation (*otherwise animations are queued*). Read more at http://api.jquery.com/stop

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/2L5Ya/2/ use the normal fadeIn and fadeOUt functions of jquery